# removing duplicates in 2-d array

Tags: c, arrays

i have 5700 rows and 3 columns of 2d array. 
have to eliminate the repeated row from that array and print only one row out of multiple repeated rows. 
count=5700.
for example,

```
24.742235   0.005334    0.052465    
27.345229   -0.222687   0.266042    
27.345229   -0.222687   0.266042    
25.528389   -0.063540   0.117000    
24.742235   0.005334    0.052465    
25.528389   -0.063540   0.117000    
24.742235   0.005334    0.052465    
25.528389   -0.063540   0.117000    
24.742235   0.005334    0.052465    
25.528389   -0.063540   0.117000    
27.345229   -0.222687   0.266042    
24.742235   0.005334    0.052465    
27.345229   -0.222687   0.266042    
25.528389   -0.063540   0.117000    
25.528389   -0.063540   0.117000    
27.345229   -0.222687   0.266042    
27.345229   -0.222687   0.266042    
24.742235   0.005334    0.052465    
24.742235   0.005334    0.052465    
27.345229   -0.222687   0.266042
```

Code:

```
for(p=0;p<count;p++)
{
  for(ppp=p+1;ppp<count;ppp++) 
  {
    if(plane[ppp][1]!=plane[p][1])
    {
      printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n",plane[p][0],plane[p][1],plane[p][2]);
      printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n",plane[ppp][0],plane[ppp][1],plane[ppp][2]);
    }
  }
}
```

i want to remove the duplicate rows from that example. row 2 and row 3 are same. so i want to display only row either 2 or 3.

Comment: Ok. What is the problem?

Comment: i want to remove the duplicate rows from that example. row 2 and row 3 are same. so i want to display only row either 2 or 3.

Comment: You forgot to post the code.

Comment: for(p=0;p<count;p++)
{
for(ppp=p+1;ppp<count;ppp++)
{
if(plane[ppp][1]!=plane[p][1])
{
printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n",plane[p][0],plane[p][1],plane[p][2]);
printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n",plane[ppp][0],plane[ppp][1],plane[ppp][2]);
}
}
}

Comment: @NagarushyanthTummala: Not in comments. Post the code with the question.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE] and do us (and yourself) a favor and format your code properly.

Comment: In general, one of the easiest ways to remove duplicates is: sort, then check if the row is the same as the next one.

Comment: can you give the logic for sorting for that kind of example??

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward function to do this is the following (note: still to be tested, so see this as the outline):

```
int A[5700][3];

int elimdups(void)
{
    int i, j, k, m, n=5700;
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {                     // for all rows
        for (j=i+1; j<n-1; j++) {               //  for all next rows
            for (k=0; k<3; k++)                 //   for each cell
                if (A[i][k]!=A[j][k]) break;    //    check cells equal

            if (k<3) {                          // row j is duplicate of row i
                for (k=j; k<n-1; k++)           //  move all rows up
                    for (m=0;m<3;m++)
                        A[k][m]= A[k+1][m];
                n--;
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```